# Guzzle pool : how to get the pool response after refactoring the anonymous function

Tags: php, class, guzzle, anonymous-function

I would like to refactor my code and use  an outside function for the anonymous fullfilled.

For instance i want to refactor the code below:

[image: Pool with return anonymous]

to something more readable (without the anonymous function). like

```
$fulfilled = New Fulfilled($phones);
$rejected = New Rejected();
$pool = new Pool(..., [
  'concurrency' => 15,
  'fulfilled' => $Fulfilled,
  'rejected'  => $Rejected,
]);
```

I created a class for fulfilled like this
[image: fullfilled_class]

But how can i get back my &$result ?

Guzzle is a puzzle.

[EDIT]
As said from Abiux, a class is not so much readable. I tried to extract the anonymous function outside the $pool like this

```
public function fulfilled($response,$index){
        $body=$response->getBody();
        $status=$response->getStatusCode();
        $reason=$response->getReasonPhrase();

        $result[] = [
          "userNumber"  => $this->phones[$index],
          "status" => $status,
          "reason" => $reason,
          "body"   => json_decode($body,true)];
   
        return $result;
  }
  // -------------------------------------
  public function get_async($phones){
   ...

    $client = new Client();

    $requests = function ($phones) use ($filter){
      foreach ($phones as $phone){
        $url="contexts?userNumber=$phone&$filter";
        yield new Request('GET', $url);
      }
    };

    $rejected = new Rejected();
    $pool = new Pool($client, $requests($phones), [
      'concurrency' => 2,
      'options'     => $options,
      'fulfilled'  => ['this','fulfilled',&$result],
      'rejected'    => $rejected,
    ]);

    // Initiate the transfers and create a promise
    $promise = $pool->promise();
    // Force the pool of requests to complete.
    $promise->wait();
    return $result;
  }
```

but it fails also

Answer (score 0):

First, don't replace anonymous function with a class. It's not more readable and it doesn't serve any purpose (as far as you have expalined).

Second, you can pass `$result` as part of the object instantiation to `__construct()` and then reference it within the `__invoke` function.

Comment: I have to agree with  a class is not so much readable. 
But the pool with a long anonymous is not so readable if the anonymous function is long. i tried to write a function outside the pool but it doesn't work either. I updated my question